# URL values not accepting when i pass as params for API

Tags: rest, java

I am passing versionName,className & namesAndValues as params for API. All are strings. In namesAndValues i am passing an url. For e.g "http://testserver.com:4000/cRelease/CM/tomcat/", it is not accepting and does not come to debug point itself. However if i replace the url with value like "TemplateBase=template_7.0.59.2.tar5" it works fine. What am i missing here?

Below is the code:

```
@GET
        @Produces({"application/json"})
        @Path("versionName={versionName}&className={className}&namesAndValues={namesAndValues}")
        public static void doGet(@PathParam("versionName") String versionName, @PathParam("className") String className, @PathParam("namesAndValues") String namesAndValues){

            try {                           
                String key=null;
                String value=null;
                HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();                                
                JSONObject jsonobject =new JSONObject(namesAndValues);              
                Iterator<String> keys=jsonobject.keys();
                while(keys.hasNext()) {
                    key=keys.next();
                    value=jsonobject.getString(key);
                    map.put(key, value);
                    }           



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Which API or package is JSONObject from? You should add the appropriate tag. (It's not part of the Java SDK because that only defines interface JsonObject, not a class.) In any case, if you construct it from just a URL (instead of a JSON formatted string) what do you expect its keys to be?

Comment: import org.json.JSONObject

Comment: I think you are mixing `@Path` and `@RequestParam`